# How to use bind variable inside collection literal in cassandra - InvalidQueryException

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm preparing a cassandra query in java using `com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement`

My schema is very simple - a `key` which is of type `text` and `value` of type `set<text>`.
I am preparing the statement like so:

`mySession.prepare("UPDATE a.table USING TTL :ttl SET value = value + {:value} WHERE key = :key ");`

[This is done in order to add a value to the set and have separate `ttl` for each value]

I got this error when evaluating the above statement:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid set literal for value: bind variables are not supported inside collection literals
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:49)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:35)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:86)
```

How can I overcome this exception and bind my variable to a collection of type `set<text>`. Alternatively, is there some better/prefered way of accomplishing my goal of dynamically (with different TTL) adding items to a `set` in cassandra from java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
PreparedStatement st = session.prepare("UPDATE test2 USING TTL :ttl SET value = value + :value WHERE name = :name ");
session.execute(st.bind()
                .setInt("ttl",1)
                .setSet("value", ImmutableSet.of("add this value"))
                .setString("name","key1"));
```